# Azure Databricks: View mount extra_configs

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

How to view the values given to the `extra_configs` parameter of an existing mounted storage in an Azure Databricks workspace (by following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts#--mount-adls-gen2-or-blob-storage-with-abfs))?

To be specific, I want to find the Client ID of the application (service principle) through which databricks is accessing mounted ADLS Gen2 storage account via a secret. Having a method to identify the Client ID will fast track renewing expired App secrets in a test environment.

Comment: Have you tried any specific approach to achieve this requirement?

Comment: No, it's not possible... And mounts aren't really recommended anymore

Answer (score 1):

- There might be no way to retrieve the configurations used to create a mount point for azure storage using service principle.
- You can try to store these values somewhere while creating the service principle itself.
- Let's say you have a table to store the source path and client id. Each time you mount a new container/storage, insert this data into your table.
- This way, you can know which client ID is used to create the mount point for storage container using service principle.

```
#create table
spark.sql("create table container_clientID(path varchar(1000), mnt_pt varchar(100), clientID varchar(1000))")

#set configs here


path = "abfss://data@datalk1603.dfs.core.windows.net/"

mnt_pt = "/mnt/repro"

#mount here

if(spark.sql(f'select * from container_clientID where path="{path}" and mnt_pt="{mnt_pt}"').count()==0):
    spark.sql(f'''insert into container_clientID values("{path}","{mnt_pt}","{configs['fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id']}")''')

#table data
spark.sql("select * from container_clientID").show()
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion @Saideep. This is a possible workaround I might consider if no other option.